I'm always interested in ideas for presenting difficult to understand topics in discussion forums
Obviously, a topic can be overly challenging.  You wouldn't, for example, invite me to speak at your online structural engineering meeting.  But I DO want to be challenging and not "dumb down" my audience.  Where does one strike a balance and find ways of keeping people interested and engaged.
I'm asking for my online group that discusses Kantian metaphysics, but it's also relevant to my offline groups that tackle difficult works of literature, e.g., Joyce.
